# Apache Spark DAG behaviour cogrouped operation

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, directed-acyclic-graphs

I would like some clarifications about the DAG behaviour, and how exactly has been handle the following job:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(1 to 10).flatMap(x=>x).zipWithIndex,3)
.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(4))

val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(List(1 to 10).flatMap(x=>x).zipWithIndex,2)
.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(3))

val rdd2 = rdd.join(rdd1)
rdd2.collect()
```

This is the related `rdd2.toDebugString`:

```
(4) MapPartitionsRDD[6] at join at IntegrationStatusJob.scala:92 []
 |  MapPartitionsRDD[5] at join at IntegrationStatusJob.scala:92 []
 |  CoGroupedRDD[4] at join at IntegrationStatusJob.scala:92 []
 |  ShuffledRDD[1] at partitionBy at IntegrationStatusJob.scala:90 []
 +-(3) ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at IntegrationStatusJob.scala:90 []
 +-(3) ShuffledRDD[3] at partitionBy at IntegrationStatusJob.scala:91 []
    +-(2) ParallelCollectionRDD[2] at parallelize at IntegrationStatusJob.scala:91 []
```

This is the spark UI image:
[image]

Looking at the `toDebugString` and at the spark UI, if I understood well, in order to perform the join, the DAG looks at what partitioner should be used and because both rdds are `HashPartitioned`,it choose the partitioner with the greater number of partitions, so `rdd` partitioner.

**Now from the spark UI, it seems that `rdd` `partitionBy` and `join` being performed in the same stage, so under this conditions, the shuffle needed for to perform the join, will be done just from one side? From one side, I mean that just the rdd1 will be shuffled and no both.**

Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You right. If both RDDs are partitioned using different partitioner Spark will pick one as a reference and reparation / shuffle only the second one.

If both have the same partitioner there is no need for a shuffle.